# JAVA InputMismatchException by using Scanner

Tags: java, exception, input

I want some inputs with Scanner by using this syntax:

```
1 2  --> Number1 Number2 --> First Number
+    --> Operator
2 4  --> Number1 Number2 --> Second Number
```

If I enter . (DOT) the program should be aborted and some math methods of the Rational Class should be executed. Here is an other example:

```
1 2   --> Number1 Number2 --> First Number
+     --> Operator
2 4   --> Number1 Number2 --> Second Number
-     --> Operator
4 -3  --> Number1 Number2 --> Third Number
```

This is my actual code:

```
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(System.in);
    Rational[] number = null;
    int number_one, number_two = 0;
    String operator = "";

    while(sf.hasNextInt()){

        if(sf.next().equals(".")){ 
            for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
                switch (operator){
                    case "+":  System.out.println(number[i].add(number[i+1]).toString());
                               break;
                    case "-":  System.out.println(number[i].sup(number[i+1]).toString());
                               break;       
                    case "*":  System.out.println(number[i].mul(number[i+1]).toString());
                               break;
                    case "/":  System.out.println(number[i].div(number[i+1]).toString());
                               break;   
                    default:    System.out.println("You can only use +|-|*|/");
                    }//Switch
                }//For 
        }
        else{

            number_one = sf.nextInt();
            number_two = sf.nextInt();
            operator = sf.next();

            number = new Rational[]{new Rational(number_one , number_two )};    
        }

    }//While
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at RationalTest.main(RationalTest.java:46) --> number_two = sf.nextInt();
```

**EDIT:**

I got it now but I still have problems. If I enter . (DOT) the program should be aborted. But after I entered a dot, I need to enter anything and after that it will be canceled:

```
1 2
+
3 4
-
2 1
.   --> it should be canceled here
1   --> But I have to enter something else. After that it will be canceled
```

New Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sf = new Scanner(System.in);
    int zaehler = 0; 
    int nenner = 0;
    String operator = "";

    while(sf.hasNextInt()){

        String z = Integer.toString(zaehler);
        String n = Integer.toString(nenner);

        if(z.equals(".") || n.equals(".") || operator.equals(".")){ 
            break;
        }else{

            int zI = Integer.parseInt(z);
            int nI = Integer.parseInt(n);

            zI = sf.nextInt();
            nI = sf.nextInt();
            operator = sf.next();
        }

    }

    sf.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is when you call "number_two = sf.nextInt();" Here you have the String input. Here it is why:
1.- First element from Scanner:

```
if(sf.next().equals(".")) //An int.
```

2.- Second element from Scanner:

```
number_one = sf.nextInt(); //An int
```

3.- Third element from Scanner:

```
number_two = sf.nextInt(); //An String
```

You must correct this.

Comment: I know what you mean but how can I fix that? 1 should be number_one = sf.nextInt(); 2 should be number_two = sf.nextInt(); + Operator is = sf.next(); I want to write those two numbers in one Row.

And why is this one an Integer?: if(sf.next().equals("."))
I thought '.next()' is for Strings only..

Comment: Yout input is this: number number sign. The Scanner stores the values in the same order they are entered. You must get the first two as integer (nextInt) and the sign as String. Or you can check the data type for the next value with "hasNextInt".

Comment: I'm desperated. How should I implement that?

Comment: @DrSyntrax do you still need help with this?

Comment: Can you explain what do you need to accomplish with the program?